# Mapping Diagram with Parallelograms

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'd like to generate a tikz figure similar to Figure 2 on page 96 of Lay et al.'s *Linear Algebra and its Applications*, but don't possess the expertise to do so nor have the time to dig through the tedious manual.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: you don't need to dig through the manual, just a few selected sections in there.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my suggestion (and please have a look [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that))

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={circle,fill=magenta,outer sep=1.5pt,inner sep=1.5pt}]
\def\plane{(0,0)--(2,0)--++(55:1.4)--+(180:2)}

\begin{scope}
\fill[blue!10] \plane;
\path (1.3,.6) node[c] (Bx) {} node[below]{$Bx$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\fill[blue!10] \plane;
\path (1.2,.8) node[c] (ABx) {} node[below right]{$ABx$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=-4cm]
\fill[blue!10] \plane;
\path (1.2,.8) node[c] (x) {} node[left]{$x$};
\end{scope}

\draw[-stealth] (x) to[bend left=45]  
node[midway,above]{Multiplication}
node[midway,below]{by $B$} (Bx);

\draw[-stealth] (Bx) to[bend left=45] 
node[midway,above]{Multiplication}
node[midway,below]{by $A$} (ABx);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

With two loops and a few styles we can draw such a diagram relatively easy.

With `xslant`ing we can use the normal [`rectangle` path operation](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#pgf.rectangle) to draw the parallelogram. The options `x` and `y` specify the lengths of the *x* and *y* unit in `(x, y)` and is used here to essentially scale the rectangles. These options are only valid for the `scope`, we usually don't want an transformation like `xslant` in the whole picture.

Another loop is placing the dots (relative to the lower-left corner of the rectangle) since we use `shift` with a loop parameter.

The `quotes` library is then used [to place nodes along the path](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.12.2). (If you want more than one option for the node you need `{}`, i.e. `"by $B$" {below, red}`.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,quotes,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  rect/.style = {fill = cyan!70!gray!25},
  dot/.style  = {shape = circle, fill = black, draw=none, inner sep=1pt},
  conn/.style = {-Stealth, bend left = 55, nodes = {node font=\scriptsize},
                 shorten > = 3\pgflinewidth, shorten < = 3\pgflinewidth},
]
\begin{scope}[xslant = .6, x = 2cm, y = 2cm]
  \foreach \sh in {0,2,4} \path[rect, shift = (0:\sh)] (0,0) rectangle (1,.75);

  \foreach \p/\pos/\l[count = \sh from 0] in {(.5, .5) / left  / x,
                                              (.5, .5) / below / Bx,
                                              (.3, .5) / right / A(Bx)}
    \node[shift = (0:2*\sh), dot, label = \pos:$\l$] (dot-\sh) at \p {};
\end{scope}

\path[conn] (dot-0) edge["Multiplication" above, "by $B$" below] (dot-1)
            (dot-1) edge["Multiplication" above, "by $A$" below] (dot-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Very cute code...

Comment: Didn't notice this before but define for example `\newcommand*{\Vector}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` and use it as `\Vector{x}` for the upright bold `x` in math-mode.